# What does the second const do in the operator function?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I found a piece of code online. But I don't understand what does the second const do in the operator function:

```
class Node {
public: 
    int row, col, val;
    Node (int r, int c, int v) : row(r), col(c), val(v) {};
    bool operator < (const Node &obj) const {
        return val > obj.val;
    }
};
```

Can anyone explain its purpose? Thank you!

Comment: It makes the function itself `const`, members of Node from the owning object may not be modified (that doesn't include `static` members or members from another object of `Node`). The `const` is also just a programmers promise, it can technically be cast away, though there's almost never a situation for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool operator < (const Node &obj) const {
```

- First `const` means `obj` is passed by const reference. That means `obj` is not expected to be changed within this `operator <` function.
- Second `const` means this is a const member function. That means `operator <` function does not change the state of the object itself (including all its data members: `row, col, val`).

Both `const` are measures for the compiler to catch unexpected changes (bugs):  either changes to the parameter or to the object state itself.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, why it's ```val > obj.val```, why not ```val < obj.val```, when overriding the ```operator <```? It really confuses me.

Comment: @TingWang it could probably a typo in your original code. From normal convention, yes, it should be `val < obj.val`